# CS0131 and CS0019. Basic logic/calculator

Tags: c#

I am merely a beginner in learning C#. I am currently working on a basic calculator with some basic logic.

Prior to calculating I want to make a two security questions. Providing the user answers correctly the option to count is supposed to appear. I am having problems with making those questions right.

This is the part in which I encountered some issues that I can not figure out:

```
if ((Twórca = Twórca.ToUpper().Trim() = "DAMIAN")
    &&(Dziewczyna = Dziewczyna.ToUpper().Trim() = "DOROTA"
        || Dziewczyna.ToUpper().Trim() = "DOROTKA"))
```

Visual Studio says that there are 3 errors here:
2x CS0131 referring to `.ToUpper().Trim()`
and CS0019 referring to `||`

Answer (score 1):

= is the assignment operator, you want == which is the equality operator

Also, you need to break this up

```
Twórca = Twórca.ToUpper().Trim() = "DAMIAN"
```

And do this instead:

```
Twórca == "DAMIAN" && Twórca.ToUpper().Trim() == "DAMIAN"
```

Otherwise you're comparing a boolean to a string in your 2nd comparison

Unless your intent was to assign that value to `Twórca` and then compare, in that case do this:

```
Twórca = Twórca.ToUpper().Trim();
Dziewczyna = Dziewczyna.ToUpper().Trim();
if ((Twórca == "DAMIAN")
    &&(Dziewczyna == "DOROTA"
        || Dziewczyna == "DOROTKA"))
```

Comment: `Twórca == "DAMIAN" && Twórca.ToUpper().Trim() == "DAMIAN"` was my first thought too, but if you look at that, it's equivalent to simply `Twórca == "DAMIAN"`. I don't think that was the intent.

Comment: Agreed, I updated my answer to address what his intentions probably were.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems:

1. You are trying to use `=` to compare two strings. This operator assigns. You want `==`, which compares two things for equality.
2. You are trying to use `=` on more than two things at a time, or you're trying to set a string inside an `if` statement (this can be done, but it is uncommon: you have to be careful about what you're doing and when to properly understand the effect your code will have).

Here's a way you could write it that will do the checks you're trying to do. It will not modify `Twórca` or `Dziewczyna`.

```
if ((Twórca.ToUpper().Trim() == "DAMIAN")
    && (Dziewczyna.ToUpper().Trim() == "DOROTA"
        || Dziewczyna.ToUpper().Trim() == "DOROTKA"))
```

It's a little inefficient, since it can run `ToUpper` and `Trim` twice on `Dziewczyna`.